# Does CAS server sends logout request to client service on CAS ticket timeout

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, cas

Recently we have integrated CAS in our project. It is working perfectly, user gets authenticated from CAS. On signing out from client application user is redirected to CAS server login page etc.

However one thing I am not able to understand is how to handle the situation where CAS ticket expires due to idle timeout, how will client application will come to know that user's CAS session has been invalidated and should logout from client application as well?

Does CAS server sends logout request to client application(services) when CAS ticket expires due to idle timeout?

Answer (score 0):

CAS Server will provide one request to all client applications at the time of log-out , in each client application web.xml we have to configure CAS log out url and action url (signout action). By using web.xml configuration CAS request will call the client application signout action. The same functionality will applicable for CAS idle timeout also.